# UE4 - Viewport mouselook always on

Tags: unreal

Does anyone know how to set mouselook to always on instead of having to click and hold the RMB?

I would press and hold a different hotkey to "disengage" mouselook and allow object selection. I was just wondering if there is an option to remap the current RMB functionality within UE4, or is it hard-coded into the editor? I'm used to using RMB as walk in a game, and have never made the switch to WASD (this goes back to the days of Doom on PC). Ideally I would like to keep my current movement mapping of RMB-A-S-D where RMB is move forward. I see where I can remap forward from 'W' but remapping it to RMB is not allowed as far as I can tell.

Comment: Explain to me how this feature would work. What happens when you move your mouse to select something from the details panel? I don't think you have thought this through.

Comment: Apologies, I should have elaborated further. I would press and hold a different hotkey to "disengage" mouselook and allow object selection. I was just wondering if there is an option to remap the current RMB functionality within UE4, or is it hard-coded into the editor? I'm used to using RMB as walk in a game, and have never made the switch to WASD (this goes back to the days of Doom on PC). Ideally I would like to keep my current movement mapping of RMB-A-S-D where RMB is move forward. I see where I can remap forward from 'W' but remapping it to RMB is not allowed as far as I can tell.

Comment: I understand now. If you update your question, I will remove my downvote :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you press the key you want to use to enable mouse selection, set a boolean variable to true and set the input mode to "UI only". When you release the key, set the boolean to false and the input mode to "Game only".

Then you just have to add forward movement when you press the right mouse button and the mouse selection boolean is false.

See example in image below where I used left shift to enable the mouse. I added this to the first person BP template and it seemed to work like you described. You may want to add a check disable mouse movement input if mouse selection is enabled, similar to how right click is disabled in the example.
[image: Example using First person BP template]